# How to make a function that yields a number under power operator by using pattern matching?

Tags: pattern-matching

Can I ask you a question related to function and pattern?

I would like to make the function below work which doesn't yield return values I expect. How can it be done?

```
f[x_]:=x/.t^2_->t;
```

The value I expect from the above function is like the example below.

```
f[3^2]
3
```

Thank you guys. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are only ever going to call it as `f[a^b]` (that is, `f[Power[a,b]]`), you want to look at the attribute `HoldFirst` (or `HoldAll` or similar). Specifically:

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst];
f[a_^2] := a
```

Alternatively,

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst];
f[x_] := Unevaluated[x] /. {a_^2 :> a}
```

I'm always wary of using `Unevaluated`, though.

Edited to add: additionally, it looks like you might be confused about the `_` syntax. `x_f` is a shorthand for `Pattern[x, Blank[f]]`. It doesn't make sense to have `2_` - that is, `Pattern[2, Blank[]]` - because `2` can't vary. Therefore Mathematica interprets it instead as `Times[2, Blank[]]` (that is, `2 _`).

Comment: Why are you wary of `Unevaluated`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: because it works so locally, and protects things only once. For instance, `Identity@Unevaluated[{1}]` is `{1}`. In any large-ish context where I need `x` to remain unevaluated, I'm (personally) quite liable to write a function where I forget to make sure `x` is still `Unevaluated` all the way through - effectively accidentally applying `Identity` to it at some point - and it takes me ages to track down the bug. I much prefer to work in a way that lets me `Inactivate` things instead, if I need to do that kind of thing.

Comment: I guess it's a matter of perspective.  I think of `Unevaluated` as momentarily setting a `HoldFirst` (or whatever position) on the Head surrounding it.  Then it is not surprising that this effect does not persist.  But as always there is room for different styles and people may go about selecting the right tool for the job in different ways.

Comment: Thank you for the answer so much, Patrick and Mr.Wizard.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this:

```
Attributes[f] = {HoldAll};
f[x_] := ReleaseHold[Hold[x] /. {Power[a_, b_] :> a}];
```

Then:

```
f[3^2]
```

gives 3.

And:

```
f[10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000^1000000000000000]
```

gives 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

And:

```
f[10^10^10]
```

gives 10

And:

```
f[(10^10)^10]
```

gives 10000000000 (10^10).

Comment: Thank you for the teaching. It was really helpful. I wish you a merry christmas. :)